# Why does a pipe remove the branch names from git log?

Tags: git, format, git-branch, git-log

when I run

```
> git log --oneline
```

I get output that looks like this

```
abcdef0 (head, branch, origin/branch) comment
0987654 different comment
1234567 (different-branch, origin/branch) third comment
```

But as soon as I pipe the output to anything (e.g. `> git log --oneline | cat`), the branch names are gone

```
abcdef0 comment
0987654 different comment
1234567 third comment
```

This means I can't grep, or add line numbers, or anything like that.

(It's also missing the colors and `less` style behavior, but I don't care about that either way today)

Is this something I can re-enable via a command-line parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For start, I too had noticed the lack of colors after a pipe to bash, but what you describe about *decorations* (branch and tag names) disappearing is odd. Let's adress them separately.

**Adressing the branch names (decorations) themselves**

```
--decorate
```

is the flag for that, for a one-shot use.

For the permanent effect, you can set it in your [config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-logdecorate)

```
log.decorate true
```

And for a more specific need, note you can use it in a pretty format, with the placeholder `%d`, for example :

```
git log -10 --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %C(reset)%aN %ar %C(red)%d %C(reset)%s"
```

for a result that looks like this

[image]

**About colors**

No, I don't know how / why it breaks when it's passed to bash, I'll let more advanced users answer that part. *(and as I said, on a personal note I'm very glad you asked this question because I'm eager to know that too **- Edit : thanks torek! :-)** )*

Comment: Explanation is that running git without telling it if you want colors or not, git will try to see if you are running on a virtual terminal (like a console) and if output is not being piped or something... if that's the case, it will resort to use color.

Comment: I think there's also the --color/--no-color option.

Answer (score 7):

The [`git log` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) is what Git calls *porcelain*.  This means it is meant to be used by actual humans, as opposed to other Git commands like [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) and [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) that are mostly or entirely meant for *computer programs* to run.

Porcelain commands are usually configurable, and often do things like color or paginate their output.  This is true for `git log` as well.  Several of the controls for this are [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) entries:

```
color.ui = auto
log.decorate = auto
```

This *auto* setting, which is the default—you can change it to `always` or `never`—tells Git: *When the command writes its output to a terminal, do it, but when it does not (like when it writes to a pipe as in `git branch | grep ...`), don't do it.*

The `log.decorate` option controls the `(master)` decorations.  Whether particular text is colored, and if so, with which colors, is controlled by a rather complicated maze of options that merely *starts* with `color.ui`.

Setting `color.ui` to `always` will break naive scripts that run porcelain commands in pipelines and expect `color.ui` to be set to its default `auto`.  None of Git's own scripts are naive like this, but you may be using your own extensions, or ones obtained from people who didn't think about the issue, so be careful when overriding these defaults.

(By the way, be careful about the `=` in settings.  These are required inside `.git/config` and `git -c color.ui=true log`, for instance, but forbidden in `git config log.decorate auto`.  It's a crazy mishmash of historical artifacts and coding whatever was expedient at the time.)

Comment: I tried `git config --global color.ui always` but to no effect (my test has been to send my usual log alias (with colors set in pretty format) through a simple grep). What did I miss? :-/

Comment: @RomainValeri: not sure, but note that `git log` doesn't use color that much on its own: it colors commit hash IDs and some `--decorate` items, and leaves much of the rest to the diff code where `color.diff` will override `color.ui`. `git log` itself takes a `--color=<when>` as well and the documentation says: "By default, colors are shown only when enabled for log output (by color.diff, color.ui, or --color, and respecting the auto settings of the former if we are going to a terminal). ..."

Comment: Meanwhile the `git config` documentation implies that `color.diff` would override `color.ui` when some program queries, e.g., `git config --get-colorbool color.diff`. I have my `color.diff` set to `auto` but `git config --get-colorbool color.diff` prints nothing for me. There's also `color.pager` and I'm not sure if this overrides other settings, although I don't set it myself.