# git show --tags > file.txt missing tags

Tags: git

When I do `git show --tags`, I get following on screen:

```
tag 8.2.0
Tagger: John Siu <john.sd.siu@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 15 23:29:18 2019 -0400

Version 8.2.0

commit 9d332de4c20c696d2e919e877509ed112de1f540 (tag: 8.2.0)
Author: John Siu <john.sd.siu@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 15 23:27:56 2019 -0400

    8.2.0 commit

diff --git a/LICENSE.md b/LICENSE.md
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..4378196
--- /dev/null
...
```

However if I redirect it to file `git show --tags > text.txt`, I get following in the file:

```
tag 8.2.0
Tagger: John Siu <john.sd.siu@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 15 23:29:18 2019 -0400

Version 8.2.0

commit 9d332de4c20c696d2e919e877509ed112de1f540
Author: John Siu <john.sd.siu@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 15 23:27:56 2019 -0400

    8.2.0 commit

diff --git a/LICENSE.md b/LICENSE.md
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..4378196
--- /dev/null
...
```

See the line starting with **commit**, **(tag: 8.2.0)** is missing.

Anyone know why and how can I get around it? This is affecting command line `grep` also if I pipe it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694961/why-does-a-pipe-remove-the-branch-names-from-git-log) is maybe related?

Comment: I don’t get it, your examples look identical to me.

Comment: @evolutionxbox just the part `(tag: 8.2.0)` is missing.

Comment: Yup. `git show` is basically just short for `git log -1 -p` or `git log --no-walk -p`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason why `git` changes the output when piping to a file, but the showing of tags can be forced by adding the `--decorate` flag:

```
git show --tags --decorate > text.txt
```

Now I get the exact same output in `text.txt` as on the console output.

Comment: The behaviour is mentioned in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorateshortfullautono but it does not explain why.

Comment: @ChrisMaes Do you know how git make it even 2>&1 can't catch it?

Comment: @JohnSiu I suspect git is detecting that you are piping the output and thus changing its output format. He is not even printing it.