# Why does git log doesn't show HEAD and branches when passed to a pager

Tags: git, git-log, pager

When passed to a pager (`git log | less`, [`watch git log`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62803231/9157799), etc), the `(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)` doesn't show up.

Comment: Note that `git log` will run the pager for you automatically by default, under various conditions. See `pager.log`, `core.pager`, and other Git settings. (This is described in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), which is very long and generally requires a lot of searching.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called *ref names*. It doesn't show up because if we don't specify `--decorate`, `git log` will use `--decorate=auto` by default.

From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/en#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorateshortfullautono):

> **If auto is specified**, then **if the output is going to a terminal**, **the ref names are shown** as if short were given, **[otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56694961/9157799) no ref names are shown**. The option --decorate is short-hand for --decorate=short. Default to configuration value of log.decorate if configured, **otherwise, auto**.

Comment: If you also want color, you can use `--color=always` or `--color`, e.g. `git log --decorate --color | less -R` or `watch -c 'git log --decorate --color'`